# React spread operator (...rest) alternatives?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm not able to include `babel-preset-stage-3` in my pipeline. Are there any alternatives to the spread operator?

I'm trying to compile the following code and it is giving syntax errors:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: How about simply using two parameters?

Comment: @Bergi there could be an arbitrary number of parameters that are passed in, specified by the user of the function.

Comment: I meant like `const privateRoute = (component, rest) => …`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [lodash.omit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.omit):

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const Component = props.component;
  const rest = omit(props, ['component'])
  return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
}
```

Comment: That is valid jsx syntax and does not rely on babel-preset-stage-3.

Comment: babel-repl: goo.gl/VNCnvW

Comment: @BryanChen That's JSX attribute spread, which is the same idea as ES object spread but handled by `react-preset-react`.

Answer (score 1):

Install `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

In your .babelrc file, add the following lines

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using this function for simplicity:

`````
                    var vals;
        console.log(typeof out)
        isobj = typeof(out) === 'object'?true:false


                if (Object.values) {
                    vals = Object.keys(obj).map(function(i) { 
           if(isobj)
             out[i] = obj[i]; 

                    })
                }else
                    vals= Object.values(obj) 
                return vals;
````}
`````

Comment: Is this simplicity?

Comment: try to have a better formatting and resolve the errors in your code.